# 12 VDC test stand for 280 A (Start-up) @ 100 A continuous air compressor

Tags: capacitor, automotive, testing

**I am working out a test stand**
that will use two [Murata](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807026688030/d1u54p-w-1500-12-hxxtc.pdf?1583754811000)
power supplies in parallel with [this board](https://power.sager.com/d1u54p-12-conc-5008402.html)
to drive an air compressor rated at 100 A continuous and a start amp draw (momentary) of up to 280 A.

I am passing power through a 150 A circuit breaker (automotive) similar to [this](https://www.walmart.com/ip/BP-CB185-150-150-Amp-Circuit-Breaker-Bussmann-BP-CB185-150-Thermal-Circuit-Breaker-150A/124819168) and a standard heavy duty relay like [this](https://adautoelectricparts.com/index.php/online-store/electrical/12v-150a-continuous-duty-solenoid-relay-for-golf-carts-300a-in-rush-1114208-detail).

My question is on the DC side (output) I was thinking I want to use a 3 farad cap in parallel to handle the start load without damaging the power supplies or overloading the distribution board (as I probably have the only one in existence).

I don't have the electrical schematic on paper but there is nothing special about it save the cap in parallel on the output side which will have to be close to the power supplies due to wire run limitations. The total wire run from the power supplies to the air compressor is roughly 12 feet. 4/0 wire.

Currently - using the automotive battery through the circuit breaker and start relay, the air compressor has no problems running at intervals of 5 to 10 minutes (with one minute run times) for several hours.

The test stand is to replicate this functionality without having to run the vehicle, ergo a test stand ...

Is this thinking correct? if not do any of you have a better suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your power supplies specify a maximum load capacitance of 0.03 F so I don't think you want to attach 3 F to the output, even if two supplies are paralleled.

If you were to add a large capacitor, I think it should be near the load rather than the supply. I know you said you have "wire run limitations", but there it is. You would also need to specify how long the startup load is present (in seconds, not just "momentary") and tell us how much of a voltage drop you can accept.

Your best solution might be using 3 or 4 supplies in parallel rather than just 2.